Fill in column based on condition with another column in R
I have the following input table:
  input <- structure(
              list(individual = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                   age = c(20, 34, 29, 30), 
                   earnings_2020 = c(0, 0, 1, 0), 
                   earnings_2021 = c(1, 0, 2, 0), 
                   earnings_2022 = c(2, 1, 3, 1), 
                   earnings1 = c(20000, 25000, 28000, 30000), 
                   earnings2 = c(30000, 36000, 39000, 40000), 
                   earnings3 = c(40000, 40000, 42000, 50000)), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA, -4L)
            )

I want to allocate the earningsNUMBER columns based on the values in the earnings_YEAR columns (i.e., the current values in earnings_YEAR represent how earningsNUMBER values should be indexed).
So in this example, as earnings_2021 == 1 for individual 1, earnings_2021 should be set to earnings1 (20,0000). earnings_2022 would be set to earnings2 (30,000) and so on. The indexing is different for each individual. The output would look like this:



individual
age
earnings_2020
earnings_2021
earnings_2022
earnings1
earnings2
earnings3




1
20
0
20000
30000
20000
30000
40000


2
34
0
0
25000
25000
36000
40000


3
29
28000
39000
42000
28000
39000
42000


4
30
0
0
30000
30000
40000
50000



Note that I don't need to keep the earnings1, earnings2, earnings3 columns but I've left them in the output table for illustrative purposes.
How can I do this easily in R? I would like to avoid using for loops as I'm working with a large dataset.
I have tried the following code but I get an error:
earnings_columns <- c("earnings_2020", "earnings_2021", "earnings_2022")
earnings_input_columns <- c("earnings1", "earnings2", "earnings3")

 df <- df %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        .cols = all_of(earnings_columns), 
        .fns = ~ {
          case_when(
            . >= 1 & . <= 3 ~ {
              input_column <- earnings_input_columns[.]
              if (!is.null(input_column) && input_column %in% colnames(df)) {
                df[[input_column]]
              } else {
                .
              }
            },
            TRUE ~ . 
          )
        },
        .names = "{.col}"
      )
    )

It produces this error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `earnings_2021`.
Caused by error in `!is.null(input_column) && input_column %in% colnames(df)`:
! 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Please provide some sample data using dput() and provide your desired output.

based on what you're saying, you don't need the content in earnings_YEAR, so can't you just delete those columns and rename earning_NUMBER by replacing NUMBER with the corresponding YEAR? If this is not a vaible solution can you give further expanation?

@Edo earning_NUMBER corresponds to a different year for each individual so this would not work. I've added some sample data using dput() and my desired output - the values in earnings_YEAR (relating to how the earnings data should be indexed) are diferent for each individual

@Edward apologies, I've added this now

erning_NUMBER are always the same or change in every row?

@Edo it changes in every row

@Chloe I have edited your input so that it contains the same fixed values your desired output had - otherwise this will lead to confusion

I think using case_when can be used here after pivoting to long form.
input %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("earnings_")) %>%
  mutate(value=case_when(value==1~earnings1,
                         value==2~earnings2,
                         value==3~earnings3,
                         .default=0)) %>%
  pivot_wider() |>
  select(-matches("earnings\\d"))

Gives
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  individual   age earnings_2020 earnings_2021 earnings_2022
       <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1          1    20             0         20000         30000
2          2    34             0             0         25000
3          3    29         28000         39000         42000
4          4    30             0             0         30000


Nice and neat approach, +1, but the case_when in the actual data might be a lot longer if there are many different columns and years. It would be good to abstract this away.

@AllanCameron - yeah, good point. Let me think about that.... maybe there aren't that many values. I'll wait for OP to comment...

@Edward yes the actual data is a lot longer - the columns go up to earnings_2060 and earnings_40

It would be a lot easier to pivot your data to long format instead of trying to cross reference columns. The following code gives the desired output but some of its complexity is due to converting everything back into wide format, which is probably not the best format to work in
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("earnings_"), names_to = "Year") %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  mutate(Year = sub("^earnings_(.*)$", "\\1", Year)) %>%
  mutate(result = grep("earnings", names(.), value = TRUE)[value]) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("earnings"), values_to = "earned") %>%
  filter(result == name) %>%
  select(-result, -name) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("individual", "age"), names_from = Year,
              values_from = "earned", names_prefix = "earnings_",
              values_fill = 0, names_sort = TRUE) %>%
  bind_cols(select(input, matches("earnings\\d")))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>   individual   age earnings_2020 earnings_2021 earnings_2022 earnings1 earnings2 earnings3
#>        <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1          1    20             0         20000         30000     20000     30000     40000
#> 2          2    34             0             0         25000     25000     36000     40000
#> 3          3    29         28000         39000         42000     28000     39000     42000
#> 4          4    30             0             0         30000     30000     40000     50000


you don't need this line of code mutate(Year = sub("^earnings_(.*)$", "\\1", Year)) %>%, you can just add names_prefix = "earnings_" to pivot_longer. The solution gets slightly more compact.

@Allan Cameron this worked, thanks!

It's easier to split your data into two separated dataframe, reshape them and join them rather that hard-code a case_when.
In this way, your code will work no matter how many conditions you have, even if they change in the future.
Try this way:
input <- structure(
  list(
    individual = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    age = c(20, 34, 29, 30),
    earnings_2020 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
    earnings_2021 = c(1, 0, 2, 0),
    earnings_2022 = c(2, 1, 3, 1),
    earnings1 = c(20000, 25000, 28000, 30000),
    earnings2 = c(30000, 36000, 39000, 40000),
    earnings3 = c(40000, 47000, 42000, 50000)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -4L)
)


# libraries you need
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# split the columns of your input
input1 <- input |> select(individual, age, matches("^earnings_\\d{4}$"))
input2 <- input |> select(individual, age, matches("^earnings\\d$"))

# reshape to longer format to match values with a join
input1 <- input1 |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(individual, age),
               names_to = "earnings_YEAR",
               names_prefix = "earnings_",
               values_to = "earningsNUMBER")
input2 <- input2 |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(individual, age), 
               names_to = "earningsNUMBER", 
               names_prefix = "earnings",
               names_transform = as.numeric)

# match earningsNUMBER to the corresponding year
output <- input1 |> 
  left_join(input2, by = c("individual", "age", "earningsNUMBER")) |> 
  mutate(value = coalesce(value, 0))

# reshape to get the table you were looking for
output <- output |> 
  select(-earningsNUMBER) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(individual, age), names_from = earnings_YEAR, values_from = value, names_prefix = "earnings_")

# final touch to have exacly the table you were looking for
output <- output |> 
  left_join(input |> select(individual, age, matches("^earnings\\d$")), 
            by = c("individual", "age"))
output
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   individual   age earnings_2020 earnings_2021 earnings_2022 earnings1 earnings2
#>        <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1          1    20             0         20000         30000     20000     30000
#> 2          2    34             0             0         25000     25000     36000
#> 3          3    29         28000         39000         42000     28000     39000
#> 4          4    30             0             0         30000     30000     40000
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: earnings3 <dbl>

Created on 2024-11-08 with reprex v2.1.0

A base R approach, getting the earnings by selecting the subset of columns. Works when the 2 subsets have equal dimensions.
earn_year <- grep("earnings_", colnames(input))
earn_ing <- grep("earnings\\d+", colnames(input))

do.call(rbind, 
  sapply(seq_along(input[,1]), \(x) 
    apply(input[x,earn_year], 1, \(y) {
      input[x,earn_year][which(y != 0)] <- input[x,earn_ing][y]
      input[x,]})))

output
  individual age earnings_2020 earnings_2021 earnings_2022 earnings1 earnings2
1          1  20             0         20000         30000     20000     30000
2          2  34             0             0         25000     25000     36000
3          3  29         28000         39000         42000     28000     39000
4          4  30             0             0         30000     30000     40000
  earnings3
1     40000
2     40000
3     42000
4     50000

